# Term filter for boolean types does not return any results

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering

I have some data with the following index (this is just the relevant piece):

```
{
  "content": {
    "mappings" : {
      "content": {
        "properties": {
          "published" : {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I query for everything using

```
GET content/content/_search
{}
```

I get back plenty of documents with `published: true`, but when I query using a term filter:

```
GET content/content/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "published": true
    }
  }
}
```

I don't get any results. What's wrong with my term filter?

Comment: I should also note that there are other properties of `"type": "string"` in the mapping that return results when they are queried the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wierd, it works for me on ES1.0:

I indexed a doc like this:

```
PUT /twitter/tweet/1
{
    "bool":true
}
```

Here is my mapping:

```
GET /twitter/tweet/_mapping
{
   "twitter": {
      "mappings": {
         "tweet": {
            "properties": {
               "bool": {
                  "type": "boolean"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I can search like this:

```
GET twitter/tweet/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "bool": true
    }
  }
}
```

I got these results:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "twitter",
            "_type": "tweet",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "bool": true
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was unrelated to querying... seems like my custom river was importing data incorrectly.